# How to pass an argument to a Bash script variable without a for loop?

Tags: bash, variable, for

I have the following script I use to make webapp conf files (under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`).

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for domain; do
    cat <<-WEBAPPCONF > /etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf
        server {
            root var/www/html/${domain};
            server_name ${domain} www.${domain};
            location / {
                index index.php index.html index.htm fastcgi_index;
                try_files $uri $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }
            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php*-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
            }
        }
    WEBAPPCONF
    ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
done

systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Given it has a `for` loop for a `domain` variable, I can run it for multiple domains by passing these domains as arguments for `domain`:

```
bash ~/nwsm domain_1.tld domain_2.tld
```

### My question

Please assume that for whatever reason I prefer not to use a `for` loop and work only with one domain each time:

If I'll remove the `for domain; do ... done` syntax, I assume I wouldn't be able to pass a domain as an argument because there isn't a `domain` variable to hold it as a value. Hence I ask what is the correct way to change the script so that it would process only one domain argument, without a `for` loop?

I'm not sure just adding `domain` at the start of the script is the correct way to do that.

### Appendix

Some weak arguments to why someone would want to even do that (because the `for loop` works quite fine to be honest):

**1)** Reducing the amount of lines when aspiring to minimalism.

**2)** Setting oneself both mentally to work with one domain at a time will reduce the chance for extra typing and typos and will ease validation of what's already written.

**3)** Using a `for` loop is redundant in some small environments when you work with a sparse number of domains (<=5 domains).

Comment: `domain=${1?missing domain}` could be useful, but you might also want to check `[ $# = 1 ]` so that extra args are not just ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
domain="$1"
test -z "$domain" && exit 2
```

**exit**

The second line is not an answer to the question. It shall solve / reduce a problem which would not be there if a loop over the positional parameters was used.

If a script is (by mistake) called without positional parameters then nothing happens in case of a loop. But a non-loop script runs in any case, potentially causing harm because the commands differ from what they should look like.

Thus it should at least be checked that the argument exists (better: check that it is a valid value). If the argument has an illegal value or is empty (non-existing) then the script should abort.

The shell builtin `exit` aborts the current shell. This works both in an interactive shell and in shell scripts. `exit` can have a non-negative integer as argument (the default is zero). This is the exit code of the aborted shell.